# How can i get XMPP subgroups?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am writing chat application using `XMPP` protocol and I use `smack` library for it.
I want to list all the `rosterEntry` groups and their subgroups.
the following code return only the main group.

```
rosterEntry.getGroups();
```

for e.g : if I use Facebook account it returns: "Facebook Friends" as name of the group, not close friend, family, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as XMPP Roster subgroups. This appears to be a Facebook specific concept.

Comment: SO, I can't have access to facebook groups or google account groups, ... ?

Comment: That really does depend how those services present this groups to an xmpp client.

Comment: I find this [Nested Roster Group](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0083.html), could this extension help me to access sub groups?

Comment: Yes, it could, but this is just a XMPP extension, e.g. Facebook would need to actually implement that.